# Sessions not returning variables

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I am fairly new to php and trying to refamilarize myself with the information. I currently have a login script that is working fine until I set the variables - it checks the user/password fine but when it redirects to the echosession.php the $_SESSION['username']; variable does not echo. Also - checking if user is logged in works and logging out as well.

```
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
session_start();
//user tabls
 $tbl_name="users";

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = md5($mypassword);
$myusername = $mysqli->real_escape_string($myusername);
$log_sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$log_result=$mysqli->query($log_sql);

  // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
  $log_count=$log_result->num_rows;

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($log_count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

// Set username session variable
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;


header("location:echosession.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

IF I try and load echosession.php as this:

```
session_start();
print("hi");
echo $_SESSION["username"];
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

The page is just empty.

Comment: is there any html above session_start(); in echosession.php?

Comment: Start by adding a default value to $_SESSION['username'] before conditional code

Comment: What's the contents of 'error_log( print_r( $_SESSION, true ));'?

Comment: @Niall, good point, session_start() should be called before anything is echoed, therefore I recommend putting it at the beginning of your code.

Comment: @Niall,  no there is no HTML and session_start() is called first.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION)` tell you?

Comment: Another thing, break your code into smaller pieces to find the bug. Put some echoes in the middle to see that the values are as expected. For example, echo $myusername; before assigning it to the session.

Comment: Try what sdespont and ethrbunny suggest and see what happens.

Comment: IF I try and load echosession.php as this:
    <?php
    session_start();
    print("hi");
    echo $_SESSION["username"];
    var_dump($_SESSION);
     ?>

The page is just empty.

Comment: add this at the beginning of your code to show all errors, who knows:  **error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set( 'display_errors','1');**

Comment: No, it doesn't print anything. Even if I add HTML above it.

Comment: @ElecBoothe If you comment out the redirect and echo $myusername what does you see then?

Comment: bootje1@gmail - the correct value to be set.

Comment: @ElecBoothe And if you go directly to echosession.php does it do anything then?

Answer (score -1):

First

```
session_start(); //always in first line.  Before include/require functions.
```

second. you can add session id for noncookies users

```
if (session cookie exists == true)
   header('location:echosession.php');
else
   header('location:echosession.php?'.session_name().'='.session_id());
```

You are 100% sure that $myusername is not empty?

check it by

```
var_dump($myusername); die(); //in first script before add to session
```

I wonder why You have no output in second script. It look like You have session problem and error reporting turned off.

Insert at script start

```
<?PHP 
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'On' ); 
error_reporting( E_ALL ); 
?>
```

Comment: The first statement is not a requirement for sessions to work. From the PHP Manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php): **To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.**... It doesn't say before any include/require like you stated. Furthermore, what if he doesn't want the sessions to start until something is executed in his code, like a custom session handler?